# What are the white lines on the edge of walls?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

When approaching the corner of a wall a small set of white ui lines appear. They can be seen in the screenshot below as two small white vertical lines.

[image: White lines]

What are they for?

Comment: To indicate a look-around-the-corner mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UI element indicates a 'mount point'.

This is a place where you can mount your weapon to enable an aim down sights view which stays until you move.

It shows up whilst around corners or hiding behind low cover, and allows peeking over cover and leaning around corners.

By default this is `T` on PC.